# Export to html file

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using php and mysql. I want to fetch data from table and export the output to the html file. Can anyone please help me out in this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: you will run this as a shell script, or inside a web server?
do you want to store the resulting html in a file?

Comment: Lots of related/duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257140/print-database-data-in-html-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013825/print-table-data-mysql-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467463/pulling-data-and-printing-it-in-an-html-table and more...

Answer (score 0):

A multistep process:

In php, establish a [mysql connection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), then  [run your query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). (linked doc pages have some examples to start with).

If you have any queries based on user input be sure to [sanitize it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).